# Postman Jetpack parse JSON response

Tags: json, testing, postman

I have a test in Postman where I do a post request and need to parse the JSON response.

The response looks like this:

```
{
"name": "John Doe",
"id": "123",
"children": [{
    "id": "A1",
    "name": "Jane Doe"
}, {
    "id": "A2",
    "name": "Jack Doe"
}]
```

}

I need to get all the 3 id's from the reponse and store them into a variable. I tried with this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("nameId", data.id);
```

In that way the id 123 is stored into `nameId`. Question is how do I parse and store the A1 and A2 id's into variables?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("firstChildrenId", data.children[0].id);
postman.setGlobalVariable("secondChildrenId", data.children[1].id);
```